# Create a label in Google Maps marker

Tags: google-maps

I want create a label in google maps marker.
I created a title but I want the text visible every time.
See my code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatLng,
map: map,
title: 'My Label'
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this example: https://jsfiddle.net/mapquintal/hpkahh8f/3/

To change the label appearance, edit the css code and to change position edit javascript code `labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(40, 0)`

Font: http://www.glerl.noaa.gov/res/glcfs/kml/test1.html

See another example: http://www.glerl.noaa.gov/res/glcfs/kml/test2.html